# PhoneGap plugins using MonoTouch and Mono for Android

Tags: cordova, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, phonegap-plugins

I realize that PhoneGap (Apache Cordova) and MonoTouch / Mono for Android are often seen as competing products.  However, I'd like to know if they can be used together.

Specifically, can [PhoneGap plugins](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) be implemented using MonoTouch and Mono for Android?

[Developing a Plugin on iOS](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS) involves writing an Objective-C class that extends the CDVPlugin class, adding *.h and *.m files to your Cordova-iOS project folder.  Can MonoTouch produce output that can be integrated with a PhoneGap/Cordova project in this format?

[Developing a Plugin on Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android) involves extending the CordovaPlugin class and overriding one of the `execute` methods.  The plugin can be distributed as a Java file or as a JAR of its own.  Can Mono for Android produce output in one of these formats?  It appears [Android Callable Wrappers](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Android_Callable_Wrappers) could be solution.

So, can C# be used to write PhoneGap plugins on either of these platforms?

**Update:**
A better way of solving this problem is to use the [Cordova WebView](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_cordova-webview_index.md.html#Embedding%20WebView) inside MonoTouch and Mono for Android apps.  This effectively lets you write your "plugins" in C#, but without having to use PhoneGap's plugin system.

Comment: I am doing something similar. Have you been successful in creating a Java Bindings DLL to the Cordova API? I am having trouble getting the CordovaInterface interface to map and can't use the WebView approach. Also, can you elaborate on how you can write C# plugins in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: [I wrote this up on my blog](http://szymonrozga.net/blog/2013/02/cordova-plugins-in-monodroid/). It's a bit lengthy as I go into details of how parts of Cordova work. Check it out here.

So I've been working on this in the past day and **it is certainly possible** in MonoDroid. I don't see why the same principles wouldn't apply to MonoTouch.

You have MonoDroid running on PhoneGap? Good. Presumably you have created the MonoDroid bindings for Cordova.

You will find that the `CordovaPlugin`, `PluginEntry` and `PluginManager` classes are accessible to you. However, some things won't be like `CordovaInterface` and a few methods that take in `org.json.*` types. We can get around this using JNI or leave it as is and get it to work.

The `DroidGap` base class implements `CordovaInterface`, so we'll use that. You will call             `base.LoadUrl(Config.StartUrl);`, at which point two important things will happen:

1. You'll be able to access the `CordovaWebView` instance using the property `AppView`.
2. You can also get a reference to the `PluginManager`, using `AppView.PluginManager`.

You need to create a custom `PluginEntry` subclass and a custom `CordovaPlugin` subclass. You have to take some shortcuts if you don't have the `CordovaInterface` type and org.json.* package properly mapped. But here is what worked for me.

```
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        base.LoadUrl(Config.StartUrl);

        var plugin = new SamplePluginEntry("Sample");
        AppView.PluginManager.AddService(plugin);
        plugin.CreatePlugin(AppView, this);
    }

    public class SamplePluginEntry : PluginEntry
    {
        public SamplePluginEntry(String service) : base(service, "UNUSED.CLASSNAME", false)
        {
            /* we'll pass klass but we'll initialize the plugin ourselves so that Cordova 
             * doesn't try to find the class name that doesn't exist */
        }

        public CordovaPlugin CreatePlugin(CordovaWebView webView, DroidGap context)
        {
            var t = new SamplePlugin();
            t.InitializePlugin(webView, context);
            base.Plugin = t;
            return Plugin;
        }
    }

    public class SamplePlugin : CordovaPlugin
    {
        private CordovaWebView webView;
        private DroidGap context;

        public void InitializePlugin(CordovaWebView webView, DroidGap context)
        {
            this.webView = webView;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public override bool Execute(String action, String rawArgs, CallbackContext callbackContext)
        {
            /* This code will execute */
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `No`

Long answer is hidden in the very nice [Architecture documents](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Architecture). Basically the tools do not support creating any kind of native package which can invoke the mono run-time and load your C# assemblies.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  The very last section, Application Startup, seems to have the most relevant information.  If mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo() can be manually called from Java to load the Mono runtime into the process then it appears this might be possible, but it would require quite a bit of low-level research.

Comment: Do you happen to have any leads on the feasibility for iOS?  Even if this isn't possible on Android, it would still be a huge win on iOS.

Comment: Fyi, got this to work in Android. Same principles should apply in iOS.